# How should I solve this limits of a series which goes to infinity

Tags: limits, hyperbolic-functions

How can I determinate

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\sinh\big(\frac{i}{n}\big)}{\sum_{i=1}^n\cosh\big(\frac{i}{n}\big)}}$$

I can't solve how should I solve this?
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please don't post picture when you can type the matter as in this case.  Pictures cannot be browsed.  The picture I see is too small to read.  Also, if you don't include some context -- where does the problem from, how far have you gotten in solving it, etc. -- it is likely to be closed.

Comment: thank you very much solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Multiply numerator and denominator by $\frac1n$ and you'll recognize two Riemann sums.